# Combine two formula in one cell using SumIF and IF functions?

Tags: excel-formula

This is the code I'm using

```
=SUMIF(OR(Entries!$A:$A,F$5&$B6,Entries!I:I)),IF(F6=0,"-")
```

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You have to provide us more information about your problem.

Comment: my sumif function works fine alone in a cell, but i want to use the "IF" function to change all "0" values to a text

Comment: Still don't know...

Comment: Can you provide a bit of sample data and what result you are hoping for?  We're not mind-readers.  You've just said that you want to combine two functions, and then provided a random-looking formula with 3 functions that don't appear to relate in any obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding how the `SUMIF()` function works. Per the [Microsoft Excel Help Database](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b): syntax is `SUMIF(range, criteria, (optional sum range))`. If you want to sum everything in your listed ranges that doesn't equal zero, you could write:

```
    =SUMIF(NAMED_RANGE,"<>0")
```

You will want to select the range you want to SUM and then name it. See this [Microsoft Office Help Page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64). Your formula is not working because you are missing the last parenthesis and you cannot put an `IF()` function instead of the required conditional statement.

If this is still confusing, you can always just create an array formula using both `SUM()` and `IF()` functions.

```
    =SUM(IF(NAMED_RANGE<>0,SUM_RANGE,0))
```

You will need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after writing this formula or it will not work.

OR you could just `SUM()` everything normally, since zeros don't add anything to the sum. You're adding a lot of work to just not add zeros.